# Magento 2 : how to addCategoriesFilter with AND condtion?

Tags: magento2

I want to filter product collection by multiple category ids with **AND** condition.
I have tried below code for same but it's not working.
below codes return products collection which has category id **1132 or 1169**.
but I want product collection which has both categories **1132 AND 1169**

```
public function getProductCollectionByCategories()
{

        $categories = [1132,1169];//category ids array
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $categories));
        return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below code...

```
public function getProductCollectionByCategories()
{
    $categories = [1132,1169];//category ids array
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    foreach($categories as $cat)
    {
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $cat]);
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: You can also do $oProductCollection->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $aCategoryIds]);

Comment: Hw to add setPageSize and setCurPage ?
When we add it it works separately for everyone . 
How to add so that it works for everyone as one unit ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$collection = $this->productCollFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('eq' => 1132));
$collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('eq' => 1169));
```

You can use `'in' => [1132]` as well because core function addCategoriesFilter map eq into in by default.